# Missing network computer list

Tags: delphi, networking

I have used for years this function (Delphi XE..Alexandria) in order to get network computer list.

```
// Workgroup = My workgroup = Ufficio

function FindAllComputers(Workgroup: string; WithIP: Boolean): TStringList;
var
  EnumHandle : THandle;
  WorkgroupRS : TNetResource;
  Buf : Array[1..500] of TNetResource;
  BufSize : cardinal;
  Entries : cardinal;
  Res : Integer;
  Computers : Tstringlist;
  Limit, I: Integer;
  Error : Integer;
begin
  Limit := 0;
  Workgroup := Workgroup + #0;
  FillChar(WorkgroupRS, SizeOf(WorkgroupRS) , 0);
  With WorkgroupRS do
  begin
    dwScope := 2;
    dwType := 3;
    dwDisplayType := 1;
    dwUsage := 2;
    lpRemoteName := @Workgroup[1];
  end;
  Error := WNetOpenEnum(RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, RESOURCETYPE_ANY, 0,
             @WorkgroupRS, EnumHandle);  // RESOURCE_GLOBALNET
  Computers := TStringList.Create;
  repeat
    Entries := 1;
    BufSize := SizeOf(Buf);
    Res := WNetEnumResource(EnumHandle, Entries, @Buf[1], BufSize);
    if (Res = NO_ERROR) and (Entries = 1) then
    begin
      Computers.Add(StrPas(Buf[1].lpRemoteName));
    end;
    Inc(Limit);
  until (Res <> NO_ERROR) or (Limit > 100);
  WNetCloseEnum( EnumHandle );
  if WithIP then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Computers.Count-1 do
    Computers[I] := Computers[I] + ' ( ' + GetIP(Computers[I]) + ' )';
  end;
  Result := Computers;
end;
```

Are severals weeks that, on all projects that this function is used, instead show all computers network is showed only the pc where the program is running.
In other word, network with 10 PCs, Workgroup=Ufficio, program running on computer with PCName=Client9N, function result is only CLIENT9N.[image]

but i have all these that are hidden.

[image]

Something change in windows?
Where i wrong?

Thank you for any reply
Daniele

UPDATE

In "Net Connection" i had NCAP.
NCAP setted a random ip address, so the above function searched all computer in a UFFICIO workgroup with that IP. The result (1) is rigth.
So,after reading several post i've uninstall it with this procedure:
"Open “Programs and Features” in the Control Panel or “Apps & features” in Settings and uninstall Npcap. Open “Device Manager” ( devmgmt. msc ) in the Control Panel and expand the “Network adapters” section. Uninstall each “Npcap Loopback Adapter” that you find."
Rebbot.

After that i have only one network adapter (rigth) but the above function does not work anymore, meaning that i have no computer list.
As Tom and Amigo suggest i have an error value: ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR (1208).

How i can do in order to return to original condition? Or There's a way to get net computers list via workgroupname and ip address?

Comment: Possibly a change in Windows. Have you searched SO for `WNetOpenEnum and/or WNetEnumResource` ? What is the error value?

Comment: no error(s) just wrong result list.

Comment: Are you sure? `Error := ` is nowhere inspected afterwards anymore - your compiler should hint that already.

Comment: Your're rigth!! Error = ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR (1208)

Comment: Have a read on [`WNetOpenEnum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetopenenuma#return-value), which also links to [`WNetGetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetlasterrora).